# Python package (tensorflow) displays mismatching versions between pip list and .__version__ output

Tags: python, tensorflow, version

I suddenly encounter this situation today, all below output is under the same environment.

`pip show tensorflow`, the output gives:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.14.0rc1
```

But, if I enter python

`python`

`>>> import tensorflow as tf`

`>>> print(tf.__version__)` . It gives:

`'1.13.1'`

I am sure I am using the same python under the environment I need with pure terminal or in IDE. This is weird, cuz I used to not having this issue. I just installed few other packages these two days, but I believe they have nothing to do with tensorflow. And you can also verify this through `pip show tensorflow` or `pip list` output to see the version is `1.14.0rc1`. So why when I actually use python, the tensorflow is not loaded properly?

Comment: "I am sure I am using the same python". Well, I wouldn't be so sure. Perhaps you can try to replicate the issue with other libraries. Another option could be that you installed both `tensorflow` as well as `tensorflow-gpu`, which are separate packages for 1.x, although I'm not sure if you can actually have both installed in parallel (they both import as `tensorflow`).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by the following:

(under the same environment)

`pip uninstall tensorflow` (in order to reinstall tensorflow the right version)

`pip install tensorflow==1.14.0rc1`

Note during installing, there is a piece of info from the terminal:

```
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
  Attempting uninstall: tensorflow
    Found existing installation: tensorflow 1.13.1
    Uninstalling tensorflow-1.13.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-1.13.1
```

So it seems like the tensorflow 1.13.1 has been accidentally installed previously, and whenever in a python program `import tensorflow`, during searching stage, it hits the `tensorflow==1.13.1` before finding the `1.14.0rc1` version. Altho `pip list` only displays `tensorflow==1.14.0rc1` but not `tensorflow==1.13.1` might also be due to its internal search or duplicated package resolve mechanism.